# Android: How to call a website without loading it on app

Tags: java, android, web

I wrote a web application in c# on visual studio, that runs a website which I can pass data to.
How can I, in my android application, call this website URL with my appended data without doing any extra steps?

I have been able to visit the website, but it loads the website on my application, I want to pass data to this website every second, so loading a web page every time is not the direction I'd like to head in.

How can I just send the data to the website, loading as little data past that as possible?

(When I write, while loading as little data as possible, I mean, that I don't want my application to visibly load the website and display it, I just want to call the website)

Thank you for reading, and any direction you can provide for me!

Update:
This is the code I am currently trying to make work, it fails for some reason I cannot figure out

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private TextView urlReturn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    String url = "http://10.0.2.2/test/Default.aspx";
    String urlParameters =
            null;
    try {
        urlParameters = "payload=" + URLEncoder.encode("AndroidTest", "UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    urlReturn = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.webStatus);
    urlReturn.setText("Return: " + executePost(url, urlParameters));

}
public static String executePost(String targetURL, String urlParameters) {
    URL url;
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    try {
        //Create connection
        url = new URL(targetURL);
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" +
                Integer.toString(urlParameters.getBytes().length));
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");

        connection.setUseCaches(false);
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);

        //Send request
        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(
                connection.getOutputStream());
        wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();

        //Get Response
        InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        String line;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(line);
            response.append('\r');
        }
        rd.close();
        return response.toString();

    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
        return "Fail!";

    } finally {

        if (connection != null) {
            connection.disconnect();
        }
    }
}}
```

So this returns fail every time, I believe I'm not far off though...

Update 2:
I need to run the call in an Async task I believe, I will post my code upon completion.

Comment: Do you want to display your website within your android app or do you want the android app to just call the phone's default browser so this external browser displays your site?

Comment: I do not want to view the website called in any shape or form.
The call includes data that the site processes, so I simply want to call the site, and that's it.

Comment: I believe I have to use a post method
But again, I am unsure if this actually loads anything client (application) side

Comment: So is it just a GET call or a POST call? Post is more complex and could include a body

Comment: My knowledge is lacking in this regard, the intent I have is to call an endpoint with some ?variables="<data>" at the end.
I would like to do this as little response from the endpoint as possible.

In other words, call the url, with the data appended, and continue operation until the next data needs to be uploaded.

Thank you for reading and responding btw, I appreciate it-

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if that actually help you but you can create a service to your android application that will connect to your server via a web service.

Comment: This would be an alternative route that I would love to entertain - given direction - I am very self-taught, if I can Google working examples, I can build it - What would I have to do exactly?

Comment: You can check the following link, which gives a way to start
[link](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/calling-restful-services-from-your-android-app/). 
Also, here is a way to create a RESTful webservice
[link](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/REST/article.html)
I hope I helped you!

Answer (score 0):

So this will be slightly different if its a POST call, but the simplest way is a GET call. Usually, in broad terms (and this could be different if the server is setup differently), GET POST and UPDATE are for this:

GET: gets a website, maybe with some parameters
POST: sends data to a website, like a form or login
UPDATE: updates something on the website, usually like a database record.

So for GET, the url is setup like this:
http://www.somewebsite.com?param1&param2&param3&param3

Notice the first ? for the first param and then & for each individual param after that.

So you need 2 files, a layout and a class.

In your layout file (your xml layout file. In this example I'll name it myXMLLayoutFile.xml) you need to add a webview. Something like this will work:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/my_webView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layoutMode="opticalBounds"
        android:padding="0dp" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

(I added a progress bar in case this takes a while to load, but you can remove it)

And then in your class file (your java file) you can do something like this:

```
public class MyClass extends Activity 
{
    ProgressBar progressBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.myXMLLayoutFile);

        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        WebView webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.my_webView);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webView.loadUrl("http://www.someurl.com?param1&param2&param3");

        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient()
        {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress)
            {
                if (newProgress == 100)
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Let me know if you have a question.

Eduardo

Comment: Hey I'm trying to place your response into an empty project, and I am getting an error.
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference
I believe I may be making a mistake... (obviously)

Comment: Oh crap I assumed you had an actionbar. Remove this line:

        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

I also just updated my answer with that line removed.

Comment: Thank you, I now get "net::ERR_CACHE_MISS"
Also, this seems to be loading a webpage viewer.
Is there a way to make the call without loading a browser? I'll be making these calls every second, and may increase the calls into the milliseconds, so loading a browser ever time is non-ideal.? Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like you're running out of cache space in your browser. If you don't want to display a website within a browser you'll need to do a lot more work, and it will depend on how the data comes. If the data is just HTML, you're gonna have to parse it and get the data you care about.
My answer answers your question on how to display a website from a url with params, but if you're gonna show this website every few seconds then you have the wrong approach to this problem. You may want to look into an API and caching data. Making network calls this often is a very bad idea.

Comment: Also, if my answer answered your question you may want to mark it as resolved and answered so it can help others in the future ;)

Comment: I guess I was not clear in my original post!
Thank you for your efforts, but this did not address what I had originally asked.